# ConcurrentModificationException on Iterator.next() but just 1 of the same code

Tags: java, arraylist, concurrency, hashmap, iterator

So i was working on a simple Java code

i have this:

```
HashMap<ObjectKey,ArrayList<DifferentObject>> HP;
```

So i used it how i wanted and it worked heres the first code:

```
FillHashMap(HP);
for(ObjectKey k:HP.keySet()){
    ArrayList<DifferentObject> temp=HP.get(k);
    for(Iterator<DifferentObject> it=temp.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
        if(it.hasNext()){
            DifferentObject OB=iterator.next();
            if(OB.Data<OtherData && OB.Time<CurrentTime){
                it.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it works like a charm, so i went out to clean my code a bit make it more presentable and now it looks like this:

```
FillHashMap(HP);
for(Object k:HP.keySet()){
  for(Iterator<DifferentObject> it=HP.get(k).iterator();it.hasNext();){
      DifferentObject OB=it.next(); (*)
      if(Condition(OB)){
           it.remove();
      }
}      
}
```

And then i get the ConcurrentModificationException on the line with the (*)
The other method that changes HP is FillHashMap and its already over by the time it reaches the for-each cycle, it really is the same code right?

Then why is giving me the error now?

Any remote help or suggestion would be apreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: So i went back to FillHashMap method:

```
FillHashMap(HashMap HP){
   Differentobject x=new DifferentObject(); 
   for(iterator over hashmap){
       ArrayList<Different Object> temp= HP.get(k);
       temp.SetSomething(int a);
       temp.add(x)
   }
```

}

if i comment the temp.add the error is gone, offcourse the program is not doing what is suppoused to do anymore, but at least now i now where it is.

By the time the loop of the 2 bit of code executes, FillHashMap should be over, but i guess its not.

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `for(Iterator<DifferentObject> it=HP.get(k).iterator();it.hasNext();){`? What is iterator in this context?

Comment: an ArrayList<> Iterator? of a custom object, is a truck class not much in it, id, capacity.

Comment: You've got a simple typographical error in your for loop as noted in my comment above.

Comment: It should be `it.hasNext()` not `iterator.hasNext()`

Comment: ah yes, that is a error i did coping the code here, is not present on the code itself, the class is quite large and theres a lot of context nessesary to understant the hole class, but my point is, that really is the same code right?

Comment: Sorry for responding to my self, i think i found the error but i still cant make much sense of it.